# Insert ignore MySql slow

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, unique

I am using this query:

```
insert ignore into CategoryLinks (article_id,category_id) values ('$art_id','$id')
```

`$art_id` and `$id` are two integers.

CategoryLinks has one unique index (both columns).

Unfortunately the query is very slow sometimes and sometimes it's fast and I don't know why!
The table has around 100,000 data records. The query needs between 1*10^(-5) seconds and over two seconds.

And it's strange that PHPMyAdmin shows: Index usage: 0B.

`show create table CategoryLinks`

```
CREATE TABLE `CategoryLinks` (
`article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(7) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`article_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Btw: Is it possible to check whether the index is used?
MyISAM is faster!

Comment: Could you share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on this table?

Comment: @charmeleon I added it to the description

Comment: If inserting one record varies so much in time, then this is probably due to load on the server.  I would investigate anything else that might have table locks, look for triggers on the table that might have dependencies on other tables, and even for network issues if the storage for the tables is on a drive accessed over a network.